# Generate a 4 digit array with unrepeated numbers in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var globalScope = {}


function generateNum() {
    globalScope.genNum = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var numEl = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9)+1);
        globalScope.genNum.push(numEl);
    }
    return globalScope.genNum;
}
```

Hello everyone. I've just started studying JS and my HW is to create a 4 digit array with unrepeated numbers from 1 to 9(for a game Bulls and Cows). But I don't know how to realize checking this array for repeated numbers. someone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: One approach is to create an array of digits from 0 to 9 inclusive, then randomly [*splice*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12) 4 members from it. That way you get random digits that aren't repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a source array containing all digits from `0` to `9`, and each time pick and remove one of them from the source:

```
function genNum(){
    var arr = [], // target array
        source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], // source array
        sourceLen = source.length,
        i, r;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random()*(sourceLen-i)); // pick a random index
        // remove it from the source and add it to the target
        arr.push(source.splice(r, 1)[0]);
    }

    // return it
    return arr;
}
```

Read more about the `.splice` method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have an array of all digits, and extract the digits from it:

```
var allDigits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    result[i] = allDigits.splice(Math.floor((Math.random() * allDigits.length) + 1, 1);
}
return result;
```

Comment: I was curious, and interestingly using a `[]` assignment instead of `push` is more than 10× faster (see the [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/push-vs-assignment-2)).

Comment: It makes sense, with the `[i]` it only writes once, with `.push()` it reads once and writes once. And the larger the array, the longer it takes to read. (That's merely an educated guess, I have no idea how it actually works).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the first thing you'll want to do when doing this from a begginers point of view would be to think what steps you need to take to do this.

**Psedocode**

```
1, Generate random number.
2, Place random number in array.
3, Loop until array length = 4:
4,    Generate random number.
5,    Check if number is in array already.
6,    If number isn't in array already then add it.
```

This makes creating the code really easy, firsy you'll want to generate a random number and then .push it into an array. Then use a while loop until `array.length === 4`. Generate more numbers in this loop and then use a `for loop` to check if the number exists in the array already,

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   //Check here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var globalScope = {}


function generateNum() {
    globalScope.genNum = [];
    while (globalScope.genNum.length < 4) {
        var numEl = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
        if (globalScope.genNum.indexOf(numEl) < 0) {
            globalScope.genNum.push(numEl);
        }
    }
    return globalScope.genNum;  
}
```

Comment: This is in O(n^2), while there’s a solution in O(n) involving another array.

Answer (score 0):

This function is essentially what you're looking for (I guess):

- First, choose a random `index` in the range `[0,10-i)`
- Then, add the digit at entry #`index` to the output array
- Finally, copy the digit at entry #`i` into entry #`index`

---

```
function generateNum()
{
    var digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var output = [];
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-i));
        output += digits[index];
        digits[index] = digits[10-i];
    }
    return output;
}
```